# Find Stack Overflow profiles based upon e-mail address

Tags: support

I am having built-in data with us. So I need to search Stack Overflow profiles so that I am passing an email id as input, and then get the exact matching profile as output.
Is there any API to do this?

Comment: You better search for the id of the user or the accountid of the user because those are public and easy stored at your end.

Answer (score 32):

You can't.

This is private information and we do not and will not give it out.